# Prevent contents div with `overflow: hidden` from moving when focus changes

Tags: html, css

I have a JSfiddle showing the problem I'm having: https://jsfiddle.net/bfmu1xzp/

There are two inputs inside of a div. That div ("inner") is larger than its parent ("outer"), which has `overflow: hidden`, such that one input is hidden. When I tab over to the hidden input, the inner div shifts (scrolls?) over to make the focused input visible.

I understand what this is a useful behavior, but I don't want it. Is there any way to prevent it?

**Note**: I'm not looking for a solution that involves simply disabling the hidden input, such that it can't be focused. This is a simplified example.

Comment: I am facing similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163444/auto-scroll-when-focus-on-elements-inside-container-with-overflow-hidden did you find a solution?

Comment: @sylvhama Not exactly. I think I just reworked the page to avoid the situation.